# Laravel Livewire testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-livewire

I am looking forward to learn Livewire and its test as well. Now I have created component for registering users and it is working fine, but when I try to do a test I get this error:
`Failed asserting that an array has the key 'redirect'.`

Here are the parts of the code:

**RegisterTest**

```
class RegisterTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

/** @test */
public function can_register()
{
    Livewire::test('auth.register')
    ->set('name', 'user')
    ->set('email', 'user@outlook.com')
    ->set('password', 'secret')
    ->set('password_confirmation', 'secret')
    ->call('register')
    ->assertRedirect('/');
}
 }
```

**Component**

```
public $name = '';
public $email = '';
public $password = '';
public $password_confirmation = '';

public function register()
{
    $data = $this->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8|string'
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy.

Add the following file:

```
->assertHasNoErrors(['name', 'email', 'password']);
```

before

```
->assertRedirect('/');
```

line and you will see it will fail. This is because your validation tells password should be minimum 8 characters and in your test it is 6 (you used `secret` as password)

Comment: This makes sense :D Thank you it is oke now.